# How to create expandable form layout on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create an insert form for new students, however I need to make a set of `EditText` fields mandatory and if the users want to fill in more, they can click the button next to the "name". Below is also a clickable `TextView` that also expands to more fields. I'm using the layout constraint.

My question is this, is there any interesting way to do this field increment so that I slide down the form as in the following gif?

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3oz8xOi32kWRnmdZYI

Comment: Please add your current layout so we can better help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use external libraries for this. Use [this](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout) for the **Expandable Layout** and [this](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) for **Validation** of your `EditText` fields.

This is a *shortcut* way. Else you can do it natively with custom `onClick` and validation.

Comment: Good, I'll test it. Saripaar I know, I'm wearing it too. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I have tried the "AAkira ExpandableLayout" that you have pointed out but, at least in my case, could not make it work. Instead, [this one](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout), works like a charm